# SQL tool to list the related tables to the parent table

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, sqlhelper, red-gate-sql-prompt

Dears,

Could you please help me to find a SQL tool that will show me the list of the tables that have relation with the parent table.  Example:

Select * from table_1

when I write **join**  there will be listed tables that **are related** to the **table_1** and after choosing one of the tables, it will also show the join based on the column PK and FK.

I have tried SQL promt but it is listing all the objects, not only the ones that I could join with **table_1**.

I am working on a DB with more than 300 tables and it is hard to find the relations between tables.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question here? To find relationships between tables look at sys.sysforeignkeys. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysforeignkeys-transact-sql

Comment: I havent needed this myself yet but I did look into it a few weeks ago out of curiosity.  Looks like they added this functionality to sqlprompt - https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/5333/special-icon-for-foreign-key-relationship-join-candidates

Comment: I just did a quick check.  The join suggestion had the foreign key relationship a the top of the list with an icon of a key next to a paperclip.

Answer (score 0):

This query would help you find tables that reference a given table.  You could also rework the query to give you the inverse if needed.

```
SELECT  
     KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS FK_CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    ,KCU1.TABLE_NAME AS FK_TABLE_NAME 
    ,KCU1.COLUMN_NAME AS FK_COLUMN_NAME 
    ,KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION AS FK_ORDINAL_POSITION 
    ,KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS REFERENCED_CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    ,KCU2.TABLE_NAME AS REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME 
    ,KCU2.COLUMN_NAME AS REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
    ,KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION AS REFERENCED_ORDINAL_POSITION 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC 

LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU1 
    ON KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG  
    AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
    AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 

LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU2 
    ON KCU2.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG  
    AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
    AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    AND KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION 
where KCU2.TABLE_NAME  = 'ReferencedTableName'
```